# People cannot hear me in Mumble

Tags: 14.04, sound, microphone, mumble

When I talk in Mumble, people cannot hear me. I can hear myself when enabling a server loopback test, so I don't think the problem is with my USB mic. I have looked at my mic in alsamixer and PulseAudio Volume Control, and it seems to be working fine. How may I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I seem to have solved my issue. I imported the certificate I had from windows and people were able to hear me again. I have no idea why the newer certificate caused this but I guess it doesn't matter as long as the older one doesn't.